# How to build a simple LED transmitter and receiver

Tags: radio, transmitter, receiver

I'd like the distance to be about 1/10th of a mile; less distance will be fine if that's easier to build. What tools and parts may I need for this? I have plenty of LEDs lying around and I have breadboards. I should add I've been working with electronics on and off for about a year so I just need directions and a tools list.

Comment: LED emitter, LED receiver, Amplifier, and a Lens to focus the infra-red beam.  Also something to encode / decode the data into the light.  Just like a TV remote control but with brighter IR LEDs and a more sensitive amplifier.

Comment: Less distance is always easier, so what's your lower limit?

Comment: IR/visible light LEDs?

Comment: Visible lights preferred

Answer (score 1):

There are several [optical free space communication designs](http://ronja.twibright.com/about.php) as part of an open source project called Ronja (Reasonable Optical Near Joint Access). They have plans, schematics and software published under the GNU Free Documentation License. They claim a **1.4km range with a stable 10Mbps full duplex data rate**, the system uses either IR or visible light LEDs with focusing optics, and interestingly does not seem to use any spectral filters.

Answer (score 0):

What will make a system like this work is the ability to focus the beam from the emitter. A regular LED converts electrical power to light power and this spreads out as distance increases - precisely like radio waves from an antenna. So, if you can focus the beam, more light power will hit the receiving device and there will be a bigger signal received - important because you'll be fighting against noise and you will need as much signal as you can get. maybe try a low power focussed laser LED as the source.

What you have lying around might work at 10m but not 150m.

Comment: for an led consider a laser diode.

Answer (score 0):

A 160 meter long visible light data link is not an easy thing to achieve with off-the-shelf LEDs and photodetectors. For comparison, I recently designed a low-power visible light transmitter, and it was only able to work at a maximum distance of ~1 m (where the bit error rate was already quite high @1 Mbps) having a receiver at the other end which was created for simple measurement purposes. It was [this LED](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/780993.pdf) with a forward current of 20 mA.

Obviously, you can use power LEDs with better directivity, lensed receivers with better responsivity/sensitivity, your environment might be less noisy, you can lower the datarate etc, but to increase the distance to 160 meters, you need components/devices that are usually not "lying around". Infrared might be somewhat less difficult, as most photodetectors tend to have better responsivity at IR wavelengths.

I recommend you to read about [free-space optical communications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_optical_communication).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with russ_hensel, a laser diode is easy to obtain and can be modulated with a transistor, transformer or another form of switching. The distance is much more then a focused led. I dont have the schematic anymore but my nephew and i made a laser voice link for his science project. Worked across his school yard with no issues other then aiming it.